# I do not understand this integral,please help...

Tags: calculus, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$$\int_0^{\infty} P(y > z) \, dz = \int_0^{\infty} \int_z^{\infty} h(y) \, dy \, dz = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^y \, dz \, h(y) \, dy$$

Why do we have the last equality? I used Fubini and derived the following:

$$ \int_z^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} h(y) \, dz \, dy.$$

Not the above result.

I THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: In all 3 of the formulas, the answer is a number.  In your formula, you end up with a function of $z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The middle integral gives us

$$0\le z<\infty\;,\;\;z\le y<\infty$$

If you now change the integration order you get

$$0\le z\le y<\infty\implies 0\le y<\infty\;,\;0\le z\le y$$

Which is precisely what you have in the third integral in the first line...

Answer (score 4):

This last integral (that you came up with) doesn't make sense - you can't use $z$ as a limit of integration outside of the $dz$-integral, because it is not defined there!

Changing the order of integration, what we are trying to do is change a set of inequalities to be in the opposite "order" as they start.

Our region of integration is initially given by the inequalities $0\leq z<\infty$ and $z\leq y<\infty$.  Note that we *first* determine a value for $z$, and once we know $z$ we can also determine a value for $y$.

To do this in the opposite order, we would first determine $y$, then determine $z$.  So, what values of $y$ are allowable here?  As it turns out, any value between $0$ and $\infty$.  Once we've chosen $y$ with $0\leq y<\infty$, we must determine acceptable $z$ values; the inequality $z\leq y$ tells us we must have $0\leq z\leq y$.

Comment: I suspect that last integral was in what I think of as "physicists' notation", in which one writes things like $\displaystyle\int dx\,f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\int_0^\infty\left(\int_z^\infty h(y)\,dy\right)\,dz = \int_0^\infty\left(\int_0^y h(y)\,dz\right)\, dy
$$

As $z$ goes from $0$ to $y$, the function $h(y)$ does not change; it is therefore a "constant" and may be pulled out of the integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty\left(h(y)\int_0^y \,dz\right)\, dy.
$$

But $\displaystyle\int_0^y dz= y$.  So we get
$$
\int_0^\infty y h(y)\,dy.
$$

I suspect the purpose was this: It was established at some earlier point that this last integral is $\mathbb E(Y)$ (*capital* "$Y$" this time, representing a random variable), and the point is to show that the integral you started with at the outset here, $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty P(Y>y)\, dy$, is also equal to $\mathbb E(Y)$.